# Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred when passing Codable struct

Tags: swift, generics, codable

Please go through the code first for better understanding.

```
func getType<T: Decodable>(urlString: String, header: HTTPHeaders, completion: @escaping (T?) -> Void){
```

}

```
let networkManager = DataManager()

 networkManager.getType(urlString: kGetMyDayTaskDetails + strId, header: header) { (MyDayAndTaskDetails) in

}
```

Error:

```
Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred
```

I am trying to pass the struct as parameter using Generics to use a common method for api calling. But not getting how to call correctly. Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider that the parameter in the closure is an **instance**, not a type. For example like

```
networkManager.getType(urlString: kGetMyDayTaskDetails + strId, 
                          header: header) { details in

}
```

To specify the generic type annotate it and according to the signature it must be optional

```
networkManager.getType(urlString: kGetMyDayTaskDetails + strId, 
                          header: header) { (details : MyDayAndTaskDetails?) in 

}
```

Comment: Please clear your answer what are you trying to say

Comment: I beg your pardon? You cannot pass the non-optional struct (the type), you have to pass an arbitrary parameter label (the instance) with annotated optional type.